# Search text file file for number and specify range and length Grep

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, cat

So I have been trying to figure this out forever and can't manage to solve it.

The aim is to filter through all lines in the text file and only show the lines with more than 4850 points and a maximum of 700,000.

The best command I have at the moment is :

grep -E '48[1-9]{2}' "filename" >> *file*

This only retrieves the accounts with points 48__ along with all the useless stuff like the customers username with this combination included, for example loggz314895.

This method will take forever as the range can go from 4850 - 700K in points and doing one at a time will take forever and filtering through the junk included.

I have a feeling its going to be a simple command but I can't manage to wrap my head around it. If one of you wizards can help me I will appreciate it. If you can break what each section of the command does too that will be really helpful.

Thanks again.

Here's an example:(has been edited for privacy reasons).

loggz@loggz1.com, userid 9826135802015973221  Points 1685, new loggz
time 111.111.111

loggz@loggz1.com, userid 9826135802015973221  Points 1685, new loggz
time 111.111.111

loggz@loggz1.com, userid 9826135802015973221  Points 1685, new loggz
time 111.111.111

Without the blank line between each user and time.

Expected output without line break:

loggz@loggz1.com, Points 1685,

loggz@loggz1.com, Points 1685,

loggz@loggz1.com, Points 1685,

Answer (score 1):

To filter columns and do comparisions, use `awk`

```
awk '4850 <= $5 && $5 <= 700000'
```

@edit

```
awk '{ if (4850 <= $5 && $5 <= 700000) { print $1,$5; } }`
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for getting back! Will this print the whole line compared rather than just printing the points with them values? Sorry it wasn't included in the case. Also can you break down whats happening? thanks man.

Comment: `printing the points with them values` that means printing only the 5th column?

Comment: Yeah sorry I Should have included more information now to think of it. I need the whole line printed out rather than just the values of the points, tbh only column 1 and 5 is needed. On the line below this loggz9492@wizard.com, LoggzThunder4893 | Points: 915 there is another line which is two collumns long. This is the pattern throughout the file. Example:

Comment: From the information you have given I have came up with awk ' {print $1, $5} where 4850 <= $5 && $5 <= 700000' but this still hasn't worked

Comment: awk is pretty streight forward. if the value on the column 5 is greater or equal to 4850 and the value on the 5th column is lower or equal 700000 then print column 1 and 5. The default "field separator" awk is uses is space. If you have some other data than in your question, please post example input and expected output. I provided the answer from the info your provided. You can edit youe question when needed. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Hey thanks man you're right, ive included more information in the original body that is identical to that of the data I am using. I feel it will be something along the lines of: awk ' {print $1, $5} where 4850 <= $5 && $5 <= 700000' but I'm not sure how to integrate something to skip every other line and that will register the comma at the end of the points?

Comment: This kind of worked, not sure why though but some of the lower values come through and some of the ones in the criteria were left out? not sure why because logic seems right and out put was correct.